# Rails 3 helper methods not available in controllers even after explicitly including them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, nomethoderror

Fist of all I'm newbie to rails.
I have this in SessionsController:

```
def method
  sign_in 'user'
end
```

And this in SessionsHelper:

```
def sing_in(user)
    ......
end
```

So Googling and reading some answers on stackoverflow let me to try something like this:
Including the **'SessionsHelper'** to the **SessionsController** and even tried to put it in **'ApplicationController'** like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  def handle_unverified_requests
    sign_out
    super
  end
end
```

But I'm getting

> **NoMethodError** : undefined method `sign_in' for  SessionsController:0x007eff2004fcd8

Also few questions:
1) What's the **point/difference in putting few methods in Heplers and few in Controllers?** Is it a security issue or what?
2) I also tried **puting the sign_in method in the SessionsController** as i read in stackoverflow that methods defined in controllers can be accessed in views. so to avoid any problems in the views I used

> helper_method

but still the same NoMethodError
3) THe best and easy way to access the helper methods in controllers?

So where am I going wrong.
I'm using **Rails 3.2.11** and **Ruby 2.0.0p0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo: your helper method is 'sing_in' instead of 'sign_in'.

Comment: Serious silly mistake. :)   Thanks for quick reply.  But still I need the other answers.

Comment: If you have a method in a controller other than a 'route' action method (like 'show', 'create', etc.), it could potentially be accessible directly from the browser, especially if you have the wildcard route set up in your routes file like:   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
Any controller methods need to be private, or moved to helpers or other "PORO"'s (Plain Old Ruby Objects). Another place to put some helper methods is a presenter object. Just search for the presenter pattern, and maybe look at the draper gem.